# No websites listed when I click the NoScript icon

Tags: javascript, noscript

I'm using TorBrowser v4.0.5 on Ubuntu v14.
I have NoScript set to "Forbid Scripts Globally".
When I encounter a webpage that doesn't work, I sometimes will turn Javascript on for that page only; but I'm finding this is more difficult to do with TorBrowser than it is with a non-Tor Firefox browser.

When I  click the NoScript icon in a non-Tor Firefox browser, it lists all the domains that supply Javascript to the current page and I can temporarily turn on JS for one or more of them until the page is working.
But when I use the Tor Browser, no domains are listed under NoScript.  Does anyone know if this is an intentional feature of the TorBrowser or if it is a bug?

If I click "Temporarily allow all this page" and then click NoScript, Options, Whitelist, only the main domain of that page is whitelisted (which usually is not really ALL the scripts on that page).
Often this is enough to get the page working, but some pages still do not work properly.  My guess is that they need JS from other domains to function.  Unfortunately, I don't know what domains they need because NoScript doesn't list them.
Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue that is less drastic than using the "Allow Scripts Globally" feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Click on 'Options' (in NoScript), then click on the 'Appearance' tab: check off the options you want see. The upper right part contains the most important ones.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion, hawkeye.  I tried all the options on the Appearance tab and none of them produced the desired result.
However, if I check the "Temporarily allow [...]" box on the Appearance tab AND ALSO uncheck "Cascade top document's permissions to 3rd party scripts" on the Advanced, Trusted tab, then NoScript starts listing all domains that supply Javascript to the page.  Mystery solved!

I'm not sure how these settings changes affect one's level of privacy when using TorBrowser, so I will ask post that as a separate question.